# Are methods in namedParameterJdbcTemplate asynchronous?

Tags: java, sql, spring, frameworks

I am inserting into a database using

`namedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(sql("num_ids"), params);`

and immediately after running a query to count the number of objects in a database during a Maven test, like so:

`int count = jdbcTemplate.queryForInt("select count(*) from num_ids where id = '123');`

My test fails, as the number of objects in the count query returns `0` when it should be `1`. Is this possibly do to an asynchronous nature of the `update()` method, and if so, what is a correct way to ensure my test runs after the `update()` method has been completed?

EDIT:

Not sure if this matters, but this test passes on Java 6 but fails on Java 8.

Comment: No the methods are all synchronous, they block until they are done.

Comment: the update is not asynchronous. i would check the logs and confirm the transaction is committed.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the only question is based on a false assumption (that updates are asynchronous), and there is no information to figure out what the problem really is.